# What is /proc/<pid>/net/dev?

Tags: linux, networking, process, proc

I'm interested in per-process network I/O counters, like those in `/proc/net/dev` and found what I thought was it under `/proc/<pid>`, i.e. `/proc/<pid>/net/dev`. But it seems that was too easy because they contain the same counters as the system.

If I diff between system and `<pid>` I get the same counters*. So that makes me wonder what is it supposed to represent? Or is it just a way to allow a specific process to read `/proc/net/dev` by setting permissions to `/proc/net/<pid>/dev` and not globally?

`man proc` does not document this and neither does http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Distro: CentOS 7.1 w/ kernel `3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64`

*`diff  <(cat /proc/<pid>/net/dev) <(cat /proc/net/dev)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/proc/net/dev` contains statistics about network interfaces, while `/proc/<pid>/net/dev` contains statistics about network interfaces *from the process' point of view*.

I suppose that if a process runs on a network namespace (see `man ip-netns`) where it has access only to a limited set of interfaces, only these will show up in `/proc/<pid>/net/dev`.